# Moving a unique_ptr in the same statement it is used

Tags: c++11, move-semantics, unique-ptr, order-of-execution

Is doing something like this safe? I'm unsure if the execution order is guaranteed or not.

```
auto foo = std::make_unique<Foo>();
foo->Bar(std::move(foo));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will work fine.

The sequence:

1. Evaluate `std::move(foo)` then evaluate `foo->` (or the other way around, which does not matter as neither changes the state of the `foo` pointer).
2. Invoke `Foo::Bar(...)` on the target object obtained in #1 passing the rvalue-casted `foo` also obtained in #1.

Probably not the cleanest code style.

Comment: But if std::move(foo) is evaluated first wouldn't foo-> try to dereference a nullptr?

Comment: `std::move` is just a type cast shortcut returning `static_cast<std::remove_reference_t<T>&&>(arg)`, it does not do anything to the object

Answer (score 0):

> Is doing something like this safe?

That works as expected by the style is not recommended because object `foo` is still available after it has been moved from. That creates a risk of bugs caused by accessing a moved from object.

Comment: I suppose that should be clear from the codebase though, if you call `std::move` you're explicitly saying _I'm not going to use this anymore in this state, and that's fine_.

Comment: @SombreroChicken I have seen such bugs in my practice despite _that should be clear from the codebase_.

Comment: Do that move deep in a conditional statement and then tell me it is clear at the top level! I don't want to have to read your code, I want to be able to trust your code!